# Redirecting Woocommerce purchase to a unique page per product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I used a code to redirect the buyer to a customised page. But I would like to add a different redirect per product category as set in Woocommerce.

This is the code I'm using to redirect for all purchases. Now I need to change it to a redirect per categegory. For example if someone buys a shop product it goed to page A and when they purchase a course it goes to page B after purchase.

```
<?php

/* Redirect user after check out */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'jay_custom_redirect_after_purchase' ); 
function jay_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    
    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.yoururl.com/your-page/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my suggestion I changed the action you selected to allow get order id. So with this informations I obtained the order items and its categories.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'jay_custom_redirect_after_purchase', 10, 1 ); 
function jay_custom_redirect_after_purchase($order_id) {

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
$categories_to_A = array('Shop');
$categories_to_B = array('Course');

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( has_term( $categories_to_A, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.yoururl.com/your-page-a/' );
        exit;
    }

    if ( has_term( $categories_to_A, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.yoururl.com/your-page-b/' );
        exit;
    }

    
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`woocommerce_thankyou`** hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_after_checkout' );
function redirect_after_checkout( $order_id ) {

    if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // set the product category slugs to redirect to
    $url_cat_A = 'https://yoursite.com/category-A';
    $url_cat_B = 'https://yoursite.com/category-B';

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        // if the product belongs to category A redirects to the product category page A
        if ( has_term( 'slug_cat_A', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $url_cat_A );
            exit;
        }
        // if the product belongs to category B redirects to the product category page B
        if ( has_term( 'slug_cat_B', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( $url_cat_B );
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

If the order contains a product from a certain category, it redirects to the corresponding product category page.

*The code must be added to the functions.php of your active theme.*